# ajax форма в модалке bootstrap в react приложении

Tags: ajax, bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

Есть две формы, одна на странице, другая в модалке.
Первая отправляет все без проблем, вторая перезагружает страницу и данные запихивает в УРЛ...

Скрипт на обе формы одинаковый. ID'шники везде разные. 
Код компанента формы:

```html
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
{/*----------Форма вертикальная шаблон------------*/}
class FormVert extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
  
  <div className="formArea">
     <form id={"Form_"+this.props.sn} className="form" autoComplete="off">
     <div className="row">
       <h4 className="formTitle2 whtxt col-md-12">{this.props.header}</h4>
       <p className="msgs ortxt col-md-12"></p>
     </div>
       <div className={this.props.tname+" row"}>
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <fieldset className="form-fieldset ui-input __first">
       <input name="uname" type={this.props.tname} id={"name"+this.props.sn} tabIndex="0" />
       <label htmlFor={"name"+this.props.sn}>
        <span>
         Введите ваше имя
        </span> 
       </label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
       </div>
       <div className={this.props.tphone+" row"}>
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <fieldset className="form-fieldset ui-input __second">
       <input name="uphone" type={this.props.tphone} id={"phone"+this.props.sn} tabIndex="0" />
       <label htmlFor={"phone"+this.props.sn}> 
        <span>
         Введите ваш телефон
        </span> 
       </label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
       </div>
       <div className={this.props.tmail+" row"}>
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <fieldset className="form-fieldset ui-input __third">
       <input name="uemail" type={this.props.tmail} id={"email"+this.props.sn} tabIndex="0" />
       <label htmlFor={"email"+this.props.sn}> 
        <span>
         Введите ваш E-mail
        </span> 
       </label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
       </div>
      <input name="formInfo" className="formInfo" type="hidden" value={this.props.title}/>
      <input name="ucity" className="ucity" type="hidden"/>
       <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-12 form-footer">
        <input  type="submit" className={this.props.btncolor+"bg col-md-12  btn-primary formBtn"} value={this.props.btntxt} />
       
       <p className="whtxt subtxt lighttxt">Нажимая кнопку "{this.props.btntxt}", Вы даете согласие на обработку Ваших персональных данных. Мы гарантируем, что Ваши данные будут использованы только для регистрации и обработки Вашей заявки. Полную редакцию "согласия об обработке персональных данных" Вы можете найти по ссылке: <a className="ortxt"> "Соглашение"</a></p>
      </div>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
  
    );
  }
}

module.exports = FormVert;
```

Код вызова первой формы:

```html
<FormVert 
title="Как повысить конверсию" 
sn="1" 
btncolor="or" 
btntxt="Повысить эффективность" 
tname="hidden" 
tphone="tel" 
tmail="hidden" 
header="Я перезвоню вам на указанный телефон и расскажу, как можно сделать вашу рекламу лучше"
/>
```

Код модалки:

```html
class CallModal extends React.Component {
   constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
   showModal: false
    };

    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }


  open() {
    this.setState({showModal: true});
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({showModal: false});
  }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
   <div onClick={this.open} className="callbackicon-square row redbg call-primary or-circle-bg">
                    <div className="callback-icon-big">  
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 960 1476">

        <g>
         <path id="recall" className="filwh" d="M9 1298l115 -250c23,-50 83,-71 135,-47l126 58c4,-6 9,-11 14,-17 46,-54 110,-127 162,-242 53,-115 68,-211 79,-281 1,-7 2,-14 3,-21l-85 -39 -41 -19c-52,-24 -75,-83 -52,-133l115 -250c23,-50 83,-71 135,-47l70 32 0 2c25,16 49,36 70,59 19,23 34,45 46,69 98,191 75,407 -82,747 -215,469 -501,545 -513,548 -27,7 -55,10 -83,9 -31,-1 -62,-5 -90,-15l-1 2 -71 -32c-52,-24 -75,-84 -52,-133z"/>
        </g>
       </svg>
     </div>
                    <div className="callback-txt">  
       <p>{this.props.txtlabel}</p>
     </div>
            </div>
            
            
            
            <div>
   <Modal className="modal-container callme" 
     show={this.state.showModal} 
     onHide={this.close}
     animation={true} 
     bsSize="small">

     <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title></Modal.Title>
     </Modal.Header>

     <Modal.Body>
     <FormVert title="Заказ обратного звонка" sn="0" btncolor="or" btntxt="Заказать звонок" tname="hidden" tphone="tel" tmail="hidden" header="Оставьте ваш номер телефона, и перезвоню вам и отвечу на все ваши вопросы"/>
     </Modal.Body>

     <Modal.Footer>

     </Modal.Footer>         
   </Modal> 
    </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Скрипт отправки данных в обработчик:

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
function wait(){ 
   
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
        // Получение ID формы
        var formID = $(this).attr('id');
        // Добавление решётки к имени ID
        var formNm = $('#' + formID);
        var message = $(formNm).find(".msgs"); // Ищес класс .msgs в текущей форме  и записываем в переменную
        var formTitle = $(formNm).find(".formTitle"); // Ищес класс .formtitle в текущей форме и записываем в переменную
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'modalform/mail.php',
            data: formNm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              // Вывод сообщения об успешной отправке
              message.html(data);
              formTitle.css("display","none");
              setTimeout(function(){
                //$(formNm).css("display","block");
                $('.formTitle').css("display","block");
                $('.msgs').html('');
                $('input').not(':input[type=submit], :input[type=hidden]').val('');
              }, 3000);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                // Вывод сообщения об ошибке отправки
                message.html(error);
                formTitle.css("display","none");
                // $(formNm).css("display","none");
                setTimeout(function(){
                  //$(formNm).css("display","block");
                  $('.formTitle').css("display","block");
                  $('.msgs').html('');
                  $('input').not(':input[type=submit], :input[type=hidden]').val('');
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    //для стилей формы
      var $input = $('.form-fieldset > input');
      $input.blur(function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('filled', !!$(this).val());
      });
}
 setTimeout(wait, 2000); 
});
```